# Meta learning network to predict weights update

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, meta-learning

I am working on a meta learning neural network that should predict the weight update of another neural network.

Here is the way I see it. Let us define the input at training step $t$ as $x_t$ and the ground truth as training step $t$ as $y_t$.
We are looking for $\omega^*$ the optimal parameters of a function $g$:
$$
\hat{y_t} = g(x_t; \omega_t)
$$

With whatever loss function, for instance: $L_t = (\hat{y_t} - y_t)^2$ and $L = \frac{1}{N} \sum_t^N L_t$ with $N$ the number of training steps.

We then have a second network $f$ defined as follows:
$$
\Delta \omega_t = f(\omega_{t - 1}, x_t, y_t ; \theta)
$$

which is the meta learner.

We want:
$$
\omega_t = \omega_{t - 1} + \Delta \omega_t = \omega_{t - 1} + f(\omega_{t - 1}, x_t, y_t ; \theta)
$$

I would like the loss function of the meta learner to be proportional to something like:
$$
L_t - L_{t - 1}
$$
so the optimization would be as fast as possible.

I thought about copying the gradient of the loss function at time $t$ with respect to the weights to the output of the meta learner $\frac{\partial L_t}{\partial \omega_t}$ but it does not work because I do not predict the weights directly but the update of the weights.

I think it is some kind of learning rate prediction but I cannot find a loss function that works well.

Can you help please?

Thank!